# Python Django Shell AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: sql, python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

[image]I am new in django please help to find out this problem. I am trying to get hello world from DB but it's not working. Have a look in my windows power shell as administration windows. I have a app articles in my django project and there I have changed the models models file and made a basic class Article with title, date and body field . Also has a function **str**

## Article model is below

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
# A MODEL IS REPRESENTED BY CLASS

class Article(models.Model):
    title : models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug  : models.SlugField()
    body  : models.TextField()
    date  : models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # ADD IN THUMNAILL LETTER

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## Command Prompt

```
Windows PowerShell

>>> from articles.models import Article
>>> Article
<class 'articles.models.Article'>
>>> Article.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: Article object (1)>, <Article: Article object (2)>]>
>>> article = Article()
>>> article
<Article: Article object (None)>
>>> article.title = "hello world"
>>> article.title
'hello world'
>>> article.save()
>>> Article.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: Article object (1)>, <Article: Article object (2)>, <Article: Article object (3)>]>
>>> Article.objects.all()[0].title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Comment: Please show the code for the Article model

Comment: Why are you posting all the lines where you wrote 'ojects' instead of objects? Post only what is needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I cleared all error typing mistake . for understanding I try to give more details

Answer (score 1):

You are defined your model with **colon** (**:**) intead of **equal to** (**=**) symbol. So Your model should be as,

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # ADD IN THUMNAILL LETTER

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Here is the image reference**,
[image]

**Update-1**

```
In [2]: # METHOD -- 1

In [3]: article_1 = Article()

In [4]: article_1.title = "my title 1"

In [5]: article_1.save()

In [6]: Article.objects.all()
Out[6]: <QuerySet [<Article: my title 1>]>

In [7]: # METHOD -- 2

In [8]: article_2 = Article.objects.create(title="my title 2")

In [9]: Article.objects.all()
Out[9]: <QuerySet [<Article: my title 1>, <Article: my title 2>]>
```

Comment: such a stupid mistake made by me. But still doesn't work